# How do I prove $\csc^4 x-\cot^4x=(1+\cos^2x)/\sin^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

How do I prove $\csc^4 x-\cot^4x=\dfrac{(1+\cos^2x)}{\sin^2x}$

Do you start from RHS or LHS? I get stuck after first few steps-

Comment: The right-hand side is currently not right. Our function on the left is $\frac{1-\cos^4 x}{\sin^4 x}$. But $1-\cos^4 x=(1-\cos^2 x)(1+\cos^2 x)=\sin^2 x(1+\cos^2 x)$.

Comment: ok I edited the identity, sorry for confusion...

Comment: hint: ${cos^2X}/{sin^2X} = cotX$

Comment: are you sure it's $1+{cos^2X}/{sin^2X}$ and not ${(1+cos^2X)}/{sin^2X}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LHS:
$$\frac{1}{\sin^4 x}-\frac{\cos^4 x}{\sin^4 x}=\frac{1-\cos^4 x}{\sin^4 x}=\frac{(1-\cos^2 x)(1+\cos^2 x)}{\sin^4 x}=\frac{1+\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is an explanation to your problem at http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Trigonometry-basics.faq.question.43447.html.

Comment: sorry about the ads on the page

Comment: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." - i.e. try from refrain from just adding a link unless the question is a reference request.